# Looking for training data for music accompaniment

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, regression, prediction

I am building a system that uses machine learning to generate an accompanying melody in real time as a leading melody is being played. It uses a type of Recurrent Neural Networks and at every step it tries to predict the next note on the accompanying track. At this point I am satisfied with just working with midi files.

I am having serious **trouble finding training data**. My original idea was to just download midi files from sites such as [mididb](http://www.mididb.com) and convert them to csv, but the problem is that **it's hard to come up with a way to distinguish between the leading melody and the accompanying melody**. Sometimes this is possible, but then again I would prefer the accompanying tracks to be always from the same (or similar) instrument(s), because different instruments are used differently (the duration and pitch of notes is very different from one instrument to the other etc.) and that would just get the network really confused.

I found Bach Corales on  [the UCI Machine Learning repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets) . The problem with this dataset though, is that it only has melodies with 1 voice. I want **datasets with 2 voices**, one of which is the **leading melody** and the other the **accompanying melody**.

I understand that this is difficult, so any advice on how to approach the problem would be very appreciated. I have tools that convert midi files to csv format, and if you can think of certain types/genres of songs, for which it would be **easy to distinguish between leading and accompanying tracks** (programmatically or manually), please let me know. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exciting Topic. There aren't much other databases out there for **data mining** other than the set you mentioned. So you'll need to get a bit creative.

Have you read Jürgen Schmidhuber's approach on music composition using LSTM Reccurent Neural Networks? If not, you should definitely do so:

[A First Look at Music Composition using LSTM Recurrent Neural Networks](http://www.idsia.ch/idsiareport/IDSIA-07-02.ps.gz)

[Finding Temporal Structure in Music: Blues Improvisation with LSTM Recurrent Networks](ftp://ftp.idsia.ch/pub/juergen/2002_ieee.ps.gz)

You can browse through his work on [his site](http://www.idsia.ch/~juergen/onlinepub.html)

Now, the first paper created their own dataset, you might try asking the authors. The training set of the latter paper can be seen [on their webpage to the study](http://www.idsia.ch/~juergen/blues/).

The best approach I think is to generate your own dataset: 

1) Note that they have used sheets (pdf) and audio (not only midi but also wav/mp3) so you might want to think about extracting chords from wav files and labeling them with possible melody harmonies manually.

2) You can search directly for single scores instead of data mining datasets. E.g. [www.free-scores.com](http://www.free-scores.com/index_uk.php3) to find specific scores. You can edit them, import them to Sibelius or Finale and convert them to midi in these programs. The easiest way would be if you can find scores written in Sibelius/Finale itself so you can export them to midi right away.

**Edit:**

One more comment on your chord/melody structure. Try to keep it simple at the beginning. Try to maintain a format like in the "First Look at.." paper: Melody+Chord Structure. No Instruments. After this is working you can try to reach the same results building this representation from multiple instrument scores. If that's working, try to build the multiple instrumentation scores from midi. If that works, start with real audio files.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's very helpful. 

www.free-scores.com seems to have exactly what I want, because I can choose scores with 2 particular instruments (i.e: bass and piano) and teach the network to say, play the bass while taking a piano melody as input. 

I'll also have a look at Jürgen Schmidhuber's approach (hadn't found it yet).